# How to add a where clause in the alias

Tags: mysql

my query

```
select `id`, `name`, `bitrixid`, `pec_public_id`, `name` as `bitrixname`, `address`, `yandex_map`, `office`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `days`, `cities`,
  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.057669) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(48.288776) ) + sin( radians(42.057669) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
    AS distance
from `a_delivery_pec_cities`
where `lat` is not null and `lon` is not null
      and name like '%Derbent%'
      and `active` = 1
order by `distance` asc
limit 1
offset 0
```

i have to add clause that alias distance < 100.

if i try with quotes like that ` or without quotes

> and `distance` < 100

i got an error " Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' "

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias in a where clause in MySQL.

```
select `id`, `name`, `bitrixid`, `pec_public_id`, `name` as `bitrixname`, `address`, `yandex_map`, `office`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `days`, `cities`,
  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.057669) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(48.288776) ) + sin( radians(42.057669) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
    AS distance
from `a_delivery_pec_cities`
where `lat` is not null and `lon` is not null
      and name like '%Derbent%'
      and `active` = 1
      and ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.057669) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(48.288776) ) + sin( radians(42.057669) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )<100
order by `distance` asc
limit 1
offset 0;
```

Comment: sorry but `ORDER BY` allows you to use `ALIAS`.

Comment: That's if the alias is defined in a subquery.

Comment: Thanks my friend for the demo!

Comment: Sorry, but you do not understand my quesion. I do not have problems with order by. I have to add  " and distance < 100 " in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING at the end of the statement

```
select `id`, `name`, `bitrixid`, `pec_public_id`, `name` as `bitrixname`, `address`, `yandex_map`, `office`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `days`, `cities`,
  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.057669) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(48.288776) ) + sin( radians(42.057669) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
    AS distance
from `a_delivery_pec_cities`
where `lat` is not null and `lon` is not null
      and name like '%Derbent%'
      and `active` = 1
having distance < 100
order by `distance` asc
```

Comment: There is a synthax error in your code, the `HAVING` clause always come before the `ORDER BY` clause.